# UE4 How to transform bone in runtime?

Tags: game-engine, game-physics, unreal-engine4, skeletal-mesh

I'm solving ragdoll replication and, I guess there's no exist clear solution for this problem
So i decided figure it out myself.

However I don't know how to transform specfied bone in runtime.

I assume the way of transform bone is using animation assets or blueprint but, It's feels not right.

What i trying to do is replicate all bone transform while doing physics(Ragdolling) but i stucked how transforming bone.

Is there any way to transform bone in c++??

Comment: You use an Animation Blueprint for such things.

Answer (score -2):

I assume the question isn't how to replicate data (and that you figured out how to do that), but how to parse and apply it.

Once you get the replicated data (likely all bones as a name, and corresponding transforms) over the network, you can use the `Transform (modify) bone` node in Animation Blueprints.

Link: https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/animation-blueprint-transform-bone-in-unreal-engine/

Comment: Please provide snippet code or example code, rather than just a link with some useless words.

Comment: @NicholasJela The question describes a huge task (not very clearly because of language skill, but it's OK), which really needs several big questions. The main issue seems to be "but i stucked how transforming bone". The linked official documentation describes in detail how to do that, hence it's far from useless. There is no "code" as Animation Blueprint is a _visual_ scripting language. However, to understand any of this before criticising, you need experience using this engine, which, judging from your tags, you don't have. Therefore I'm confused why you even need to leave such a comment.